# Cannot show option selected with templateResult select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

```
function formatCountry(country) {

    if (!country.id) {
        return country.text;
    }
    var $country = $(
        '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-' + country.id.toLowerCase() + ' flag-icon-squared"></span>' +
        '<span class="flag-text">' + country.text + "</span>"
    );
    return $country;
};

$("[name='country']").select2({

    templateResult: formatCountry,
    data: isoCountries
});
```

I use this code for country select, but when I refresh page, option selected return dafault value.

Comment: Set your selected value to local storage and when page refresh get the value from local storage and set to drop down.

Comment: I've tried follow your way but, it still return default value in option.
This is my html:
<select name="country" id = "language" style="width: 150px;"></select>

Comment: You need to set your value on document.ready.Or make fiddle of your work I shall check.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/sgb4888k/2/)
I make follow this code, and insert js :
$(function() {
                if (localStorage.getItem('language')) {
                    $("#language option").eq(localStorage.getItem('language')).prop('selected', true);
                }

                $("#language").on('change', function() {
                    localStorage.setItem('language', $('option:selected', this).index());
                });
            });
but it still return default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local storage like this.

```
$("[name='country']").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a country",
  templateResult: formatCountry,
  data: isoCountries
});
var OldValue = localStorage.getItem("Key");
if (OldValue !== "" && OldValue !== null) {
  $('select').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a country",
    templateResult: formatCountry,
    data: isoCountries
  }).select2('val', OldValue);
}
$("[name='country']").on("change", function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  localStorage.setItem("Key", selected);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgb4888k/224/)

Run fiddle multi-pal time and you can see the result.

Comment: But as your code, icon flag of country will disappear. I tried and it still don't work.

Comment: If its solve your problem accept and up vote the ans. Happy Coding :)